# Pdfmake Uncaught invalid image error even with correctly url

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

When I try to download PDF file with image generated by pdfmake I got:

```
 Uncaught invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries (or local file paths in node.js)
```

I have visited playground on their [website](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) but I got there the same error.

Here I paste the [example](https://pastebin.com/j9CrMFMg) url to image generated by my server. It works fine as you can see (paste it to the browser url).

Finally I posted code:

```
 pdfMake.createPdf({
    content:[{image: 'url from paste bin here'}]
  }).download();
```

Honestly I have ran out of ideas.

Comment: I tried using the image here https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/Xadvz/ and it did not work for me either. I was using Safari.

Comment: this is strange because it works perfectly in flask python (I render images from url posted in pastebin) but somehow it does not work in js and website examples

Comment: If you go to http://pdfmake.org/playground.html and click the **IMAGES** link, there is a working example on line 34, although the text editor does not show the value it is there. Weird, kind of seems buggy in their editor when using base64.

Comment: Seems that jpeg does not work neither. On their website I got that error "Unrecognized document structure" and empty "" instead of jpeg url. On my client it generates pdf but when I try to open it shows out of memory error.

Comment: Ok problem solved. I had to get rid of urllib.parse.quote when I was saving url to image on server and leave only base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode().

Answer (score 0):

You can include local JPGs and PNGs from your filesystem if you put them in the ./images folder from the pdfmake root. Then they will be referenced as "./images/filename.jpg" (or .png as the case may be). [EDIT: Also, images won't load above a certain filesize in preview. They will still work on server side rendering. I had a 4.7 MB PNG that would render just fine server side but no matter what, can't get it to render on the client. So just be sure to be using small images if you want to use the dev playground clientside preview feature.)